# Spring Data Mongo can not process entity inhretance correctly

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data Mongo in my project, as the following:

1. Spring Data MongoDB 1.2/ Spring Data Commons 1.5
2. Spring 3.2.2 RELEASE
3. MongoDB / QueryDSL 2.9/ Mongo Java Driver 2.10.1

**Case 1:** @Id from the spring data commons, @Document is from Spring data Mongo.

```
@Document
class User{
    @Id String id;
}


@Document
class Picture{
    @Id String id;
}

@Document 
class Avatar extends Picture{
    @DBref User user;
}
```

Neither I used Spring Data Repostory api or QueryDSL one, I can not get the avatar data by user.

```
//decalred in repository
List<Avatar> findByUser(User user);

// or from the QueryDSL executor
List<Avatar> avatars=rep.findAll(QAvatar.avatar.user.eq(user));
```

All return empty collections(of course there are some data in it).

**Case 2**: If I remove @DBRef, in the first time, after I have insert the avatar and user, it worked, but when I updated the data in User, then get the avatar by user, return empty list.

```
@Document 
class Avatar extends Picture{
    User user;
}
```

**Case 3**: change the User to String(userid), it works.

```
@Document 
class Avatar extends Picture{
    String userId;
}
```

Any suggestion for java modeling for MongoDB here? Thanks.

Comment: I have created some demo codes for spring data and legacy dao support...QueryDSL for Data JPA worked well, but for Data Mongo, it did not work. https://github.com/hantsy/conference/tree/master/snippets, in the data-mongo, it is based on Spring data mongo, the query based on Mongo template and Query expression worked, but when I used Dbref, and use reference path in the QueryDSL, it did not work.